# Hopefully simple permutations question

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

Say I have a permutation $B_{1}=(2,4,1,3).$ Now I'm thinking about
a permutation $\sigma_{2}$ that gives me the permutation $(4,2,1,3)=\sigma_{1}$
from $B_{1}$, $\sigma_{2}B_{1}=\sigma_{1}.$ To clarify, $\sigma_{2}$
needs to take 2 to 4, 4 to 2, etc. That is, $B_{1}(1)=2$, $\sigma_{2}(2)=4$,
$B_{2}(2)=4$, $\sigma_{2}(4)=2$, $B_{3}(3)=1$, $\sigma_{2}(1)=1$,
$B_{4}(4)=3,$ $\sigma_{2}(3)=3$. In the end, I get $\sigma_{2}=(1,4,3,2)$.

Given $\sigma_{2}$ chosen as above, let's consider the set of permutations
of $B_{1}$ where only $2$ and $4$ can be permuted and $1$ and
$3$ can be permuted; that is, the (restricted) set of permutations
of $B_{1}$ are $B_{\pi}=\{B_{1},B_{2},B_{3},B_{4}\}$, where $B_{1}=(2,4,1,3)$,
$B_{2}=(2,4,3,1)$, $B_{3}=(4,2,1,3)$, $B_{4}=(4,2,3,1)$). \textbf{The
question is}: How can I be sure in general that $\sigma_{2}B_{i}$
will always lie in $B_{\pi}?$ for $i=1,2,3,4$, given that $\sigma_{2}$
was only chosen to make $\sigma_{2}B_{1}=\sigma_{1}$, where $\sigma_{1}\in B_{\pi}$
?

Edited!

Comment: I cannot understand anything you have written. Firstly $\mathcal{B}$ appears to be an ordered pair of sets rather than a set. Then you refer to a permutation in $\mathcal{B}$ and I don't know what you mean by that, and I don't know what $B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4$ are supposed to be, etc.

Comment: I've edited my question. Thanks for the comment. Does it help?

Comment: So when you write $B_1=(2,4,1,3)$ you mean $B_1(1)=2$, $B_1(2)=4$, $B_1(3)=1$, $B_1(4)=3$. Is that right? I ask because I think many people would assume that it meant $B_1(1)=3$, $B_1(2)=4$, $B_1(3)=2$, $B_1(4)=1$.

Comment: You are correct. Another example $\sigma_{2}B_{2}=(4,2,3,1)$, which
lies in $B_{\pi}$ because $B_{2}(1)=2$, $\sigma_{2}(2)=4$, $B_{2}(2)=4$,
$\sigma_{2}(4)=2$, .$B_{2}(3)=3$, $\sigma_{2}(3)=3$, $B_{2}(4)=1$,
$\sigma_{2}(1)=1$.

Comment: OK, so what do you mean by the "set of permutations of $B_1$"?

Comment: The full set of permutations of $B_{1}$ would contain the 24 permutations
$\{(1,2,3,4),(2,1,3,4),...(4,3,2,1)\}$ but I'm actually considering
a subset of this set called $B_{\pi}$ , as given above.

Comment: But you haven't defined what you mean in general by the set of permutations of a permutation. You are using too many ideas without explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The way I interpret your answer from left to right I get
$$
(1\,4\,3\,2)(2\,4\,1\,3)=(1\,2\,4\,3)
$$
and from right to left I get
$$
(1\,4\,3\,2)(2\,4\,1\,3)=(3\,4\,2\,1).
$$
Neither is the answer you seek. Try this from left to right
$$
(1\,2\,3\,4)(2\,4\,1\,3)=(4\,2\,1\,3)
$$
or from right to left
$$
(1\,2\,3)(2\,4\,1\,3)=(4\,2\,1\,3).
$$

Comment: In my notation, (1 4 3 2)(2 4 1 3)  means that the value of the element in the ith position of the second vector, b(i), is relabelled according to the value of the b(i) element of the first vector. So b(1)=2, and a(2)=4. So 2 is relabelled 4.

Comment: Generally these things are read from right to left. These are cycles so when you type $(2\,4\,1\,3)$ that is the permutation that takes $2\to 4\to 1\to 3\to 2$. When you want the composition of two cycles, you analyze what happens to each element under the right one first, e.g. $2\to 4$ and since the next one to the left doesn't contain 4, 4 remains fixed, thus 2 goes to 4 and 4 is the first element of the new cycle composition. Since 4 goes to 1 and 1 goes to 2, 4 goes to 2 in the new cycle composition. 1 goes to 3 and 3 goes back to 1, 1 remains fixed. Similarly 3 is fixed as well.